# Multiple JSON keys in my API. How can I display different CollectionViewCell with a KEY parameter?

Tags: swift

Question: I have multiple JSON keys in my API. What I am trying to do is when one of my keys in my JSON is **-> verb: "shared" or -> verb: "posted"** I want it to display a different UICollectionViewCell.

I am doing everything programmatically. I am doing the MVC approach.

My model is below:

```
struct myModel: Decodable {
    var verb: String?
    var date: String?
    var type: String?
    var style: String?
    var image_url: String?
    var id: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against storing your `verb` property as a String as it requires you to compare hardcoded strings to find out what your collection view cell is going to look like. Instead, you should probably use an enum:

```
struct MyModel { // Type names should use pascal case in Swift
  var verb: State?
  ....
  enum State {
    case shared
    case posted
  }
}

// Decode your enums from strings
extension MyModel.State: Decodable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case shared
    case posted
  }
}
```

Then create the cell you need in your UICollectionViewDataSource:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let model = ... // retrieve your model object here
   if model.verb == .shared {
     // Pass the pertinent identifier
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:...)
     return cell
   else {
     ....
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I am doing it and it is saying My.Model.State does not conform to protocol 'Decodeable' and ask me to add this. ->     init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        <#code#>
    }

Comment: Do I add that? And if I do, what do I put inside of there? I really appreciate the help on this

Comment: If you don''t mind, can we go on the stackoverflow chat?

Comment: I also have other Keys in the JSON that are not hardcoded. I have some that are hardcoded and some keys that are not hard coded. This is what I have so far with what Swift is telling me to do. The "String?" is the one that is not hard coded and I need to get that from the JSON. I am attaching a google doc so you can take a look at the code I have so far, if you dont mind. Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JfV4CCbO_718PSnyYnHZCbiNL3Wc8msqRU0pabE1KAI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can we go on Skype chat? I am still having trouble with the above. It would be much appreciated!